# Determine category for a given URL

Tags: python, text-classification

I would like to determine for a given URL as an input a category from a list of categories (e.g. programming, health, vegan food, computer science, math).

```
cats = [ "programming", "health", "raw vegan food", "vegan cooking", "computer science", "math" ]

def getCategory(url, cats):
  ...
```

I would like to do it, without having to download a lot of data for deriving the category. I have already searched a lot of what is available, but I'm starting to information overload, losing in lot of data about NLP, topic modeling.

I have found gensim library, but not sure if it's able to do this conversion.
So, if you can provide certain direction, it would be really helpful.

Comment: You will have to use topic modeling to solve this. I recommend you check out the NLTK library

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how would you ever be able to determine what category *www.myrandomwebsite.com* is in?

Comment: You won't be able to do so reliably, but topic modeling is a good place to start if you want somewhat accurate classification.

Comment: @lordingtar Thanks, this is good to know, if it has sense to dive into studying it now. Maybe I will close it as too general. I wanted something that is able to recognize subtle differences. between "raw vegan food" and "vegan cooking" but it looks like information overload will be here for some time yet.

Comment: Use a neural network! Nerual nets are great and does all things ! :D